# Convert HEIF images to a more common image format in Java

Tags: java, heif

I need to convert server-side HEIF images (new Apple/iOS format) to a more common image type (e.g. JPG, PNG, ...). Is there any solution Java-based?

I couldn't find any library or other solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, checked some months ago, there is no (native) Java based solution yet. You could connect existing external libraries e.g. via JNI, but that would always be platform-dependent.

Comment: Thank you. After all search I made I think you are true. At this moment, there is no Java-only solution.